# Matplotlib Scatter Plot without Color Blending

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to turn off color blending for a scatter plot, but I'm not seeing how that might work. I tried markerfacecolor with plt.plot but I'm still getting blending behaviors. This is definitely achievable in plotly, but I can't seem to figure it out in matplotlib.

Here are three sample scripts that produce the same graph below. The first one fur sure enables blending (alpha adds up with overlaying points), but this is what I'm trying to avoid. The following two create the same graph still although I thought they might turn off blending.

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets
boston = datasets.load_boston()
data = pd.DataFrame(boston['data'])
data.columns = boston['feature_names']
data['target'] = boston['target']
```

```py
plt.figure(figsize=[5,5])
plt.scatter(data["CRIM"], data["RM"], alpha=0.5)
```

```py
plt.figure(figsize=[5,5])
plt.scatter(data["CRIM"], data["RM"], c=(0.12156862745098039, 0.4666666666666667, 0.7058823529411765, 0.5))
```

```py
plt.figure(figsize=[5,5])
plt.plot(data["CRIM"], data["RM"], 'o', markerfacecolor=(0.12156862745098039, 0.4666666666666667, 0.7058823529411765, 0.5))
```

[image: scatterplot with blending]

Would definitely appreciate if anyone has figured this out before, thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post examples of "blended" and "non-blended" scatter plots? also, post your code. no one can suggest edits to your approach without seeing it.

Comment: `(0.12156862745098039, 0.4666666666666667, 0.7058823529411765, 0.5)` is RGBA...

Comment: You should also post a sample of your data or your entire dataset if it's not too large

Comment: @BigBen ah so that just does the same thing as alpha then

Comment: @coelidonum, it's the boston dataset but I just my extraction code